# Do all masses with equal mass density, whatver their form is, reach the same end velocity, falling from infinity to the surface of earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, friction, projectile, drag

Is the end velocity for every object (regardless its form) the same when it reaches the face of the earth (the object's mass is negligible with respect to earth) from infinity? Let's assume the material of the mass can withstand temperatures so that it doesn't melt in the atmosphere and that the atmosphere is at rest.

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333369/2451

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially asking if a parachute and a bowling ball will fall equally and end at the same final speed. This is **not happening**.

The gravitational accelerations $g$ are equal, because they do not depend on shape or size nor mass ($g=GM/r^2$ where $M$ is the planet mass). If gravity was the only force, then the final states *would indeed* be equal (still assuming that the falling objects have negligible masses and sizes compared to the Earth.)

But **air resistance** is a force that depends on the shape (on the perpendicular cross-sectional area to be precise). It is present whenever an object moves through/relative to the air - so whenever there is an atmosphere - and is typically modelled as:

$$F_d=\frac 12\rho C_D A v^2$$

where $\rho$ is air density, $C_D$ a drag coefficient depending on the exact atmosphere as well as surface texture of the object, $A$ the cross-sectional area seen from the falling direction and $v$ the relative speed. A parachute will catch more air because of it's larger $A$ and thus feel more air resistance.

Simply plugging these into Newton's 2nd law shows that the accelerations experiences will be different for two equally masse but differently shaped objects:

$$\sum F_1=ma_1\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad F_g-F_{d,1}=ma_1\\
\sum F_2=ma_2\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad F_g-F_{d,2}=ma_2$$

$a_2>a_1$ if $F_{d,2}<F_{d,1}$. Different accelerations cause different final speeds.

Comment: Re "If gravity was the only force, then the final states would indeed be equal." This is incorrect. The impact velocity will be rather different in the case of the Earth and a bowling ball colliding versus the Earth and a neutron star colliding.

Comment: @DavidHammen Thank you for the comment, I am assuming the masses to be negligible compared to the Earth mass as the question sets as an initial assumption. I have added it as a note. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

Even without an atmosphere the two speeds will be different due to the tidal forces. An easy way to see this is to consider two masses attached by a massless rod oriented radially. The acceleration of the center of mass is $a_{cm}=(F_1+F_2)/m$, where $m=m_1+m_2$ and the $F$'s are the forces on the individual masses. For  given individual masses $m_i$ and position of the center of mass $x_{cm}$ the total force will change with the length of the rod (you can either write the expression or notice that as the rod length increases, the force on the closer mass increases and that on the farther mass decreases, but at different rates). Thus, different lengths will feel different accelerations (and different velocities) at the same center of mass position.

Answer (score 1):

> Do all masses, whatever their form is, reach the same end velocity, falling from infinity to the surface of earth?

Of course not. Ignoring atmospheric effects, the impact velocity of a collision between an airless Earth and a spec of dust will differ significantly from that between an airless Earth and a neutron star. Assuming two spherical objects with spherical mass distributions, the impact velocity from a parabolic trajectory (relative velocity at infinity=0) will be $\sqrt{2\frac{G(m_1+m_2)}{r_1+r_2}}$

This reduces to approximately $\sqrt{2\frac{Gm_1}{r_1}}$ in the special case $m_2 \lll m_1$ and $r_2 \lll r_1$. In that special case of small objects colliding with the Earth, then yes, all tiny objects will impact an airless Earth with more or less the same speed.

All bets are off after accounting for atmospheric drag. At any moment in time, the drag force on an object can be expressed as $F_d = \frac12 C_d\, \rho\, v^2 A$, where $c_d$ is the coefficient of drag, $\rho$ is the density of the atmosphere at that locale, $v$ is the velocity of the object with respect to the atmosphere at that locale, $A$ is the object's cross sectional area to drag, and $C_d$ is the object's dimensionless coefficient of drag. Dividing by mass yields the acceleration due to drag: $a_d = \frac12 \frac{C_d\, \rho\, v^2 A}{m}$.

Given two objects with the same coefficient of drag and the same density but different masses, the larger object will be subject to less drag acceleration than will the smaller object, roughly inversely proportional to radius. Given two objects of the same density and same mass, one may experience significantly more drag acceleration than the other thanks to different coefficients of drag and different cross sections.

Bottom line: There is no reason to expect that different objects of different masses and different shapes will reach the same end velocity after falling from infinity to the surface of the Earth.